# Open Web Analytics is not working in netscape, Any solution to overcome?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am working in web analytics. I have found [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) is `open source` and having comparable features with `Google Analytics` and also having more features also. so i thought of using Open Web Analytics. But I came to know [Open Web Analytics is not supported in `Netscape`](http://web-analytics-software.findthebest.com/compare/1-9/Google-Analytics-vs-Open-Web-Analytics.)

Any solution to overcome this issue in Open Web Analytics.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why you add php here?

Comment: Why in the world do you need netscape compatibility ?

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara Open Web Analytics is developed using mysql and php..

Comment: a) Netscape is defunct so why do you care b) OWA does note have "more features" than GA and c) that link of yours is wrong about quite a number of things so you should not base your decision on this.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff : More Features I mean to say data gets stored locally(prevents data leakage) and heatMap option is there.